# DecisionTreeClassifier with strings and prediction int

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a code that fetches some datas from my database
database part isn't that important because I sorted my datas without any problems.

but the thing is in the ML part I want to fit 3 strings and 1 integer to give me some predictions

code:

```
import mysql.connector
from sklearn import tree

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='amin', password='123', host='127.0.0.1', database='truecar')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM cars;"
cursor.execute(query)

x = []
y = []

for (id, name, mileage, condition, price) in cursor:
    car_spec = []
    car_spec.append(name)
    car_spec.append(mileage)
    car_spec.append(condition)

    x.append(car_spec)
    y.append(price)

cnx.close()


clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(x, y)
```

and the error is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Toyota FJ Cruiser'
```

I know it can't be string but is there a way to do that?

example of my data:

```
['Toyota FJ Cruiser', '168,766 miles', '4 accidents, 3 Owners, Fleet use']
$12,999
```

I want my code to learn the input list and based on those datas, predict a price for me
(I know price is not integer too but I can handle it.... I just want sklearn to predict things based on strings, not floats)

Comment: Based on your example row of data, you need to apply preprocessing to name (use categorical conversion), mileage (pass only the number), and extract info from condition in numbers format. Although, you can also try to use AutoML with your data. I can recommend MLJAR: https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classifiers usually don't work with strings. You need to **convert** your data into numbers.

You can either represent each class written as string by a number see [Categorical Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)
or you represent it with 0/1 matrices where each class becomes a binary column marking if the class is present see [One-hot Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

With those two keywoards you should be able to proceed.